# Add margin and crop marks to existing PDF

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

In order to prepare PDF files for printing, I'm looking for a commandline/programmatic way to modify existing PDF files and do the following:
- add a white 3mm margin to each side of each page (so the new PDF will become 6mm larger in width and 6mm larger in height)
- add crop marks on each page

Here are a few commands I experimented with:

I first tried to add a BleedBox, but that didn't have the desired effect as it didn't resize the pdf:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf -c "[/BleedBox[54 54 1314 810] /PAGES pdfmark" -f in.pdf
```

The following ghostscript command enlarges the pdf and adds a white margin at the top and right of each page, but the content is not centered:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf -r300x300 -g3000x3000 -f in.pdf
```

I also tried to resize the pdf with imagemagick, but the following command also scaled the content of the pdf:

```
convert -density 300 -colorspace RGB -quality 100 -border 200x200 in.pdf out.pdf
```

So far, I haven't found any way to add the crop marks.

Could anyone please help me out with the margins and crop marks?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: Could you please show us what you tried with ghostscript & Imagemagick? Because: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with the commands I experimented with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the above FPDF/FPDI code sample I managed to add the bleed and crop marks. 
The only difference is, that I'm drawing the crop marks as lines and not putting an image in the corners.

For those of you wanting to do the same, here is the code to add both bleed and crop marks to an existing pdf:

```
    $bleedInMM = 3; // the bleed in mm on each side
    $pdfWidthInMM = $this->getPdfWidthInMM();
    $pdfHeightInMM = $this->getPdfHeightInMM();

    //width and height of new pdf. the value of $bleedInMM is doubled to have the bleed on both sides of the page
    $newWidth = ($pdfWidthInMM + ($bleedInMM * 2); 
    $newHeight = ($pdfWidthInMM + ($bleedInMM * 2);

    $pdf = new \fpdi\FPDI(
            $pdfWidthInMM > $pdfWidthInMM ? 'L' : 'P', // landscape or portrait?
            'mm',
            array(
                $newWidth, 
                $newHeight
            ));

    if (file_exists($srcPdfFilePath)){ 
         $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($srcPdfFilePath); 
    } else { 
        error_log("Error! file: ".$srcPdfFilePath." does not exist");
        return FALSE; 
    } 

    // make the crop line a little shorter so they don't touch each other
    $cropLineLength = $bleedInMM - 1;

     for($i=1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) { 
         $tpl = $pdf->importPage($i); 
         $pdf->addPage(); 
         $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpl);

         $pdf->useTemplate($tpl, $bleedInMM, $bleedInMM, 0, 0, TRUE); 

         $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.25);

         // top left crop marks
         $pdf->Line($bleedInMM /* x */, 0 /* y */, $bleedInMM /* x */, $cropLineLength /* y */); // horizontal top left
         $pdf->Line(0 /* x */, $bleedInMM /* y */, $cropLineLength /* x */, $bleedInMM /* y */); // vertical top left

         // top right crop marks
         $pdf->Line($newWidth - $bleedInMM /* x */, 0 /* y */, $newWidth - $bleedInMM /* x */, $cropLineLength /* y */); // horizontal top right
         $pdf->Line($newWidth - $cropLineLength /* x */, $bleedInMM /* y */, $newWidth /* x */, $bleedInMM /* y */); // vertical top right

         // bottom left crop marks
         $pdf->Line(0 /* x */, $newHeight - $bleedInMM /* y */, $cropLineLength /* x */, $newHeight - $bleedInMM /* y */); // horizontal bottom left
         $pdf->Line($bleedInMM /* x */, $newHeight - $cropLineLength /* y */, $bleedInMM /* x */, $newHeight /* y */); // vertical bottom left

         // bottom right crop marks
         $pdf->Line($newWidth - $cropLineLength /* x */, $newHeight - $bleedInMM /* y */, $newWidth /* x */, $newHeight - $bleedInMM /* y */); // horizontal top right
         $pdf->Line($newWidth - $bleedInMM /* x */, $newHeight - $cropLineLength /* y */, $newWidth - $bleedInMM /* x */, $newHeight /* y */); // vertical top right
     }

     return $pdf->Output($destinationPdfFilePath,'F');
```

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

Check http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about

See following snippet to add 3mm to the document using the library. You can also add an image (the cropsigns) using the same library. You still need to find out how to place them in the corners though...

Kr

W

```
require_once('library/fpdf.php');
require_once('library/fpdi.php');

$name="cropsign.png";
$im = imagecreatefrompng($name);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 255, 0);
imagepng($im,$name);

$pdf = new FPDI('P','mm',array(213,300));// original 210/297 for A4 document
if (file_exists("./".$file)){
    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);
} else {
    echo 'Fail';
    return FALSE;
}
 for($i=1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
    $tpl = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tpl, 1, 1, 0, 0, TRUE);
    $pdf->Image($name, $xxx, $yyy, 0, 0, 'png');
    $pdf->Image($name, $xxx, $yyy, 0, 0, 'png');
    $pdf->Image($name, $xxx, $yyy, 0, 0, 'png');
    $pdf->Image($name, $xxx, $yyy, 0, 0, 'png');
}
if ($outdir === TRUE){
    return $pdf->Output();
} else {
    return $pdf;
}
```